# Differential equation with a Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I have a piecewise function:

$$
f(t) =
  \begin{cases}
    7  & 0 < t < \pi \\
    -7 & \pi < t < 2\pi
  \end{cases}
$$

and it's assumed that when  f (t)  is extended to the negative t-axis in a periodic manner, the resulting function is even. Therefore, the particular solution is a cosine series.

The differential equation given is:
$$
8 \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 9x = f(t)
$$

The particular solution is in the form of:
$$
x_p(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \ \cos{\frac{n\pi t}{p}}
$$

**Problem**: I am trying to retrieve $A_n$.

---

I tried to find the particular solution using the method of undetermined coefficients:

$$
x_c (t) = c_1\cos{\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}t} + c_2\sin{\frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}t}\\
x_p (t) = C \cdot A_n \cos{\frac{n\pi t}{2 \pi}}
$$

Using $C \cdot A_n \cos{\frac{nt}{2}}$, differentiating and plugging into the DE:

$$
8(\frac{-Cn^2}{4} \cdot A_n \cos{\frac{nt}{2}}) + 9(C \cdot A_n \cos{\frac{nt}{2}}) = C \cdot A_n \cos{\frac{nt}{2}} \\ 
C = (9-2n^2)
$$

Finding $A_n$ using Fourier Cosine series and @Dylan's answer:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 7 \cos{\frac{n}{2}t} \ dt + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} -7 \cos{\frac{n}{2}t} \ dt = 28 \frac{\sin{\frac{n}{2}n\pi}}{n\pi}
$$

Using $C = (9-2n^2)$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n (9-2n^2) \cos{\frac{n}{2}t} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 28 \frac{\sin{\frac{n}{2}\pi}}{n\pi} \cos{\frac{n}{2}t}\\
A_n = 28 \frac{\sin{\frac{n}{2}\pi}}{n\pi(9-2n^2)}
$$

Comment: Why would you just integrate the right side? That won't give you a particular solution. If you want to do it by integration, then you should convolve with the Green's function. But a simpler way to do it here is just undetermined coefficients.

Comment: I see. I revised the post and used the method of UC, and found a "solution". Is this what you meant?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5B8+y%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+9+y%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+++++Piecewise%5B%7B%7B-7,+-2+%5C%5BPi%5D+%3C+x+%3C+-%5C%5BPi%5D%7D,+%7B7,+-%5C%5BPi%5D+%3C+++++++++x+%3C+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D,+%7B-7,+%5C%5BPi%5D+%3C+x+%3C+2+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%7D,+0%5D,+y%5Bx%5D,++++x%5D+%2F%2F+FullSimplify

Comment: You should have $(9-8n^2)A=A_n$ so $A=(9-8n^2)^{-1} A_n$. (It also would be better to use different notation, because really your $A$ also depends on $n$...)

Comment: Ok I changed the notation, hopefully it's more easier to read.

Comment: What is the period of $f$? If it is $2 \pi $ then the resulting function is odd and you should be looking for a $\sin $ series.

Comment: It's t + 2$\pi$ , the function is even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have noticed that $\sin(n\pi)=0$. This is the first sign that your answer is wrong.

Since $f(t)$ is an even function, its period is $4\pi$, not $2\pi$. Hence, $f(t)$ is represented accordingly as

$$ f(t) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos\left( \frac{n}{2}t \right) $$

Integration should be over $[0,2\pi]$. You have two separate integrals to do here: one for the constant term and one for $n\ne 0$

\begin{align} 
A_0 &= \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\ dt}{\int_0^{2\pi} 1\ dt} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\ dt \\
A_n &= \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\cos\left( \frac{n}{2}t \right)  dt }{\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \left(\frac{n}{2}t\right)\ dt} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\cos\left( \frac{n}{2}t \right) dt 
\end{align}

You'll need to break them up into integrals over $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$, since $f(t)$ is piece-wise

Once you have the Fourier series of $f(t)$, you can make a guess for $x_p$ of the form

$$ x_p(t) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\cos\left(\frac{n}{2}t\right) $$

Note that this expression corresponds to $p=2\pi$ in your given formula. Then

$$ 8\ddot{x}_p + 9x_p = 9c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (9-2n^2)c_n\cos\left(\frac{n}{2}t\right) $$

Comparing coefficients gives

\begin{align}
9c_0 &= A_0 \\
(9-2n^2)c_n &= A_n
\end{align}

In this example, you conveniently have $A_0=0$. But this is not true for the general case, so the constant term should always be considered.

Comment: Thank you!! I found $c_n$ to be $\frac{28sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n\pi}$.. Does that seem about right?

Comment: If you mean $A_n$ then that looks right.

Comment: Thank you for your help again. One last thing: Since the cosine series involves $\cos{\frac{nt}{2}}$, plugging the respective derivatives for the particular solution should result in $(9-2n^2) c_n \cos{\frac{nt}{2}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll fix the answer.